# Planning the design for a questionnaire program

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class

I'm planning to create a program where the user can respond `open questions`. The answers of these open questions can be numeric (let's go to say that the answer is a decimal for precition) or string.

For example, in decimals, represent 50% of 1 (this is the reason for numeric as answer). And sometimes is convenient strings.

I'm analysing how I could design the program.

OpenQuestion contains as properties, `QuestionText`, this could be abstract. Then we could derive two classes called StringOpenQuestion and NumericAnswerQuestion, and these one contains the datatype as decimal and string. I'm not sure if it would be great that this one were generic.

What do you think?

Comment: I think you are overthinking this thing. Start doing some code, and ask some specific question about your code. There is other StackExchange for code design. I think it is: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras is right - I don't understand what you're asking enough to give an opinion on it.